# Breaking up expression to sub-expressions

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

If I write following code, I get this error message:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

If I remove the if/else statement it works. But I would like to either show there the value or the currency first, depending on the currency. So how would you break up this code?

```
 if item.currency == "%" {

      Text(item.currency)
           .font(.system(size: 14, design: .rounded))
           .padding(.bottom, 0)
           .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

      Text(item.value)
           .font(.system(size: 24, design: .rounded))
           .fontWeight(.heavy)
           .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

 } else {

      Text(item.value)
           .font(.system(size: 24, design: .rounded))
           .fontWeight(.heavy)
           .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

      Text(item.currency)
           .font(.system(size: 14, design: .rounded))
           .padding(.bottom, 0)
           .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use provided snapshot as the only content of view `body` there is no error, so I assume it is part of much more complex view hierarchy. For such cases I prefer to break such structure apart into explicit view property as in following example

```
var body: some View {
    ItemCurrencyView // << usage
}

private var ItemCurrencyView: some View { // < separated view builder
    Group {
        if item.currency == "%" {

            Text(item.currency)
                .font(.system(size: 14, design: .rounded))
                .padding(.bottom, 0)
                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

            Text(item.value)
                .font(.system(size: 24, design: .rounded))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

        } else {

            Text(item.value)
                .font(.system(size: 24, design: .rounded))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)

            Text(item.currency)
                .font(.system(size: 14, design: .rounded))
                .padding(.bottom, 0)
                .frame(width: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

as variant it can be also a function ItemCurrencyView, if preferred.